# quick and simple way to sort this data taken from a tsv and make it distinct as per one of the fields that it contains

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, visual-studio-2008, csv

I want to know the quickest and simplest way to sort the code shown below. Sorting from newRecord.AppCode would not be suitable as it will change the meaning of the output. So I need to sort every line from string outp. What would be the best way? Also I would like to make every row distinct. I beleive using LINQ would be very quick but I am not that great at it. Help appreciated. So close to getting it done! Note: Data is being pulled from a tsv. Using .net 3.5, visual studio 2008) Will mark answer as soon as I get progress. :)

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] splitted = line.Split('\t');
                appcodes.Add(line);
                Records newRecord = new Records();

                newRecord.Server = splitted[0];
                newRecord.Instance = splitted[1];
                newRecord.AppCode = splitted[2];
                newRecord.Database = splitted[3];
                listrecords.Add(newRecord);
                for (int i = 0; i < appcodes.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (newRecord.AppCode==appcodes[i].ToUpper())
                    {
                        String outp = newRecord.AppCode + "  " + newRecord.Server + "  " + newRecord.Instance + "  " + newRecord.Database;


                        Console.WriteLine(outp);
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: why would you downvote?? worked on it. Asked a question for help, I think thats why this page exists. Worked on the answer myself and found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have lists named Keepers and newkeepers. Was trying to do something like outp.sort() and outp.sort() but it doesnt work in strings.  This is how I solved the problem.

```
 Keepers.Add(outp);

Keepers.Sort();

 newKeepers = Keepers.Distinct().ToList();

foreach (object o in newKeepers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, newrecords contain different fields so I wrote a LINQ statement to solve the problem.

```
 var sorted_list = (from r in newrecords
                                   orderby r.AppCode, r.Server, r.Instance, r.Database
                                   select r).Distinct().ToList();


                var distinctSortedList = sorted_list.Distinct().ToList();
```